# HttpContext.Current.Session - NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

I have been experiencing a **Object Reference not set to an instance of an object** error in my MVC 4 ASP.NET project's Settings class, that gets my Current Session details.  Each time I browse a page the variable throws the **NullReferenceException**, and could not understand why, because it was working previously perfect without any issues.

```cs
namespace TracerCRM.Web
{
    public class Settings
    {
        public static Settings Current
        {
            get
            {
                Settings s = HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"] as Settings;
                if (s == null)
                {
                    s = new Settings();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"] = s;
                }

                return s;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following things that I encountered during my research:

1: ["HttpContext.Current.Session" vs Global.asax "this.Session"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464456/httpcontext-current-session-vs-global-asax-this-session)

2: [Rare System.NullReferenceException show up for a HttpContext.Current.Session["courseNameAssociatedWithLoggedInUser"] that was previously populated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483170/rare-system-nullreferenceexception-show-up-for-a-httpcontext-current-sessionco)

3: [The Session object is null in ASP.NET MVC 4 webapplication once deployed to IIS 7 (W 2008 R2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947975/the-session-object-is-null-in-asp-net-mvc-4-webapplication-once-deployed-to-iis)

4: [Log a user off when ASP.NET MVC Session expires](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25541704/log-a-user-off-when-asp-net-mvc-session-expires)

5: [Login Session lost sometimes when redirect to action in asp.net mvc 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18049865/login-session-lost-sometimes-when-redirect-to-action-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

None of the above worked for me.

Comment: When you say "because it was working previously perfect without any issues", the "it was working" part is before wrapping your Settings logic in the `Settings` class?

Comment: no, I had to start working on a new development in the project, DayPilot Calendar Control, and since then, I have experiencing this problem.

Comment: @Hennie check my answer and tell me if something is not clear.

Comment: @mybirthname, I have tried it, and still same error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        public static Settings Current
        {
            get
            {
                if(HttpContext.Current.Session == null)
                {
                     Settings s = new Settings();
                     return s;
                }
                if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"] == null)
                {
                    Settings s = new Settings();
                    HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"] = s;
                    return s;
                }

                return (Settings)HttpContext.Current.Session["Settings"];
            }
        }
```

You are wrapping the `Session["Settings"]` to Setting class when it is null. If you change the code like this it should work.

**Learn to use debug in the future, you will resolve errors like this really fast !**

Comment: Use debug and see what is null in the current case. Is it session null ? :D

Comment: @Hennie check it now.

Answer (score 7):

Add this Global.asax.cs

```
using System.Web.SessionState;

protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.
        SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```